# SQL Count not counting "NULL" in column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I am learning MS SQL & trying to count users entered in record table that are not equal to actionID(column) value 21. Below is the query but it's not giving me result as expected. Its not considering the NULL value. It's showing count as 0, however it's should show result as 1. I have NULL value in actionID column field

```
Select COUNT(*) from db.record where userID ='xyz' AND NOT actionID = 21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is for MySQL** You need a `NULL`-safe comparison:

```
NOT actionID <=> 21
```

Almost all comparisons to `NULL` return `NULL`.  And `NOT NULL` is still `NULL`

For MS SQL use it like below

```
 (actionID <> 21 OR actionID is null)
```

Comment: Thanks!! How we will do it in MS SQL as "<=> " gives us error. It tried to write "is NULL" for safe comparison but it's still have error in query execution

Comment: @NetworkEngExploringCoding . . . Your question is tagged MySQL and this provides a MySQL solution.

Comment: Thanks! It works with MySQL. For SQL, is used it like - AND (actionID != 21 OR actionID is null)